# properties of a norm

Tags: real-analysis

I am quite bothered by this problem in Royden's 4th ed. Show that $||f||=\int_{a}^{b} {x^2 |f|}$ is a norm given that $f\in L^1$ on $[a,b]$.

I want to show that $||f||=0$ iff $f=0$.
Am I doing this right?
if suppose $||f||=0$ then $||f||=\int_{a}^{b} {x^2 |f|}=0$
that is, $0=||f||=|f| \int_{a}^{b} {x^2 }$
then $|f|=0$ thus $f=0$.
am i right to assume that $|f|$ is a constant?

Comment: $f$ is only in $L^1$.  How are you taking it out of the integral?

Comment: so it is wrong to assume that it is a constant. Right. L1 is the collection of integrable functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that $\int_a^b x^2 |f|$ means $\int_a^b x^2 |f(x)|dx$ so that $|f|$ is no constant.

Hint: $\int_a^b g(x) dx =0$ with $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ imply that $g(x) = 0$ almost everywhere, i.e. $g=0$ in $L^1$.

Comment: so i can let $g(x)=x^2|f(x)|$? and since $x^2 >0 $ for all x and $|f(x)|$ is a nonnegative function then surely, $g(x)>0$?

Comment: yes, that's right ;-)

Comment: am i right to assume the definition of $|f|=f^+ + f^-$ hence |f| is nonnegative?

Comment: yes, you can assume $|f(x)|\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$...

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inequality:
$||f+g|| = \int_a^b x^2 |f(x)+g(x)|dx \leq \int_a^b x^2 (|f(x)| + |g(x)|)= \int_a^b x^2 |f(x) + \int_a^b x^2 |g(x)| = ||f|| + ||g||$
Therefore
$||f+g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$

Positive Homogeneity:
$||\alpha f||= \int_a^b x^2 |\alpha f(x)| dx =|\alpha| \int_a^b x^2 |f(x)| =|\alpha| ||f||$
Therefore $||\alpha f || = |\alpha| ||f||$

Nonnegativity: Trivial
Therefore $||f||=\int\limits_a^b x^2 |f(x)| dx$ is a norm.

Comment: ya, i am done with this part. was just quite confused with the part where $||f||=0$ implies $f=0$